# How to fix invalid source argument when using JSON from API

Tags: python, json, petl

Im trying to pull financial data from the polygon.io API to organize it and later inject it into an Azure database.  In order to accomplish this I have been using the "petl" python package but I am having issues starting with an example table because of an invalid source argument that I believe to be caused by how I am retrieving and writing the JSON result.

```
import petl as etl
import websocket
import json
import requests

r =requests.get("https://api.polygon.io/v1/historic/forex/AUD/USD/2018-2-2?limit=1&apiKey=*********") 
#gets data includes plenty of responses that arnt text
data = json.loads(r.text)

table1 = etl.fromjson(data, header=['day','map','msLatency','pair','status','ticks','type'])
print(table1)
```

I expected a table with the column headers being the ones listed with their values underneath but instead received this error message: `"AssertionError: invalid source argument, expected None or a string or an object implementing open()"`

When printing the data from the API it looks like this:

```
{'day': '2018-2-2', 'map': {'a': 'ask', 'b': 'bid', 't': 'timestamp'}, 'msLatency': 1, 'pair': 'AUD/USD', 'status': 'success', 'ticks': [{'b': 0.80392, 'a': 0.80392, 'x': 0, 't': 1517529600225}], 'type': 'forex'}
```

I have tried converting the data or using the api call line as the data argument but have had little success

Comment: It's telling you that is expects `None` or `a string` or `an object ...`, so what you get from `r.text` (better use `r.content.decode()`) is a string, so no need to use `json.loads`, try calling: `table1 = etl.fromjson(r.content.decode(), ...)`

Answer (score 0):

The `petl.fromjson` call expects a string, (the path to a local file), or None, (stdin).  You have pulled the JSON (text) from the URL and converted it to a Python dictionary.  So you should be thinking in terms of dictionaries, not the JSON format of the source.  I can see several possible solutions:

- Don't run `json.load`, just write the response to a temporary file, then call [petl.fromjson](https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/io.html#petl.io.json.fromjson) on the file.
- Don't use [petl.fromjson](https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/io.html#petl.io.json.fromjson), since your data is no longer JSON, use [petl.fromdicts](https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/io.html#petl.io.json.fromdicts), which can load from dictionaries.  (In fact, inside the code, petl.fromjson essentially calls `json.load`, then calls [petl.fromdicts](https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/io.html#petl.io.json.fromdicts).
- If you work with a *lot* of data, then you might want to wrap the request in an [io Helper](https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/io.html#i-o-helper-classes) so it pulls from the URL while reading and passing to further PETL functions.